# Com Port data sending Issue

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, led

i am sending data i.e 12345 to a LED display connected with my COM port,But it show 12344 instead of 12345 on LED.I have check it through Hyperterminal and found that there is no issue in LED Display.
My code is adding "4" at the end by itself.Need help in this issue

Mycode :

```
  With comPort


            '.ParityReplace = &H3B                    ' replace ";" when parity error occurs 

            .BaudRate = 9600
            .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
            .DataBits = 8
            .StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
            .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
            '.Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
            '.RtsEnable = False
            '.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1             'threshold: one byte in buffer > event is fired 
            '.NewLine = vbCr         ' CR must be the last char in frame. This terminates the SerialPort.readLine 
            '.ReadTimeout = 10000


        End With


        Try

            comPort.Close()
            If comPort.IsOpen = False Then
                comPort.Open()
            End If
            Dim a As String = ""
            For i As Integer = 0 To 4

                comPort.WriteLine("12345") ' & Char.Parse(32))
            Next



        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error Open: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: Is the last char changed if you try `Write` instead of `WriteLine`?

Comment: This is undiagnosable.  Why is there an "a" variable?  What is the point of the For loop?

Comment: You are most likely overrunning the receive buffer on the LED. Why is the handshaking turned off? How fast are you sending data down the port (not the baud rate, but comPort.Write)? How big is the input buffer on the LED? Why do you close the comPort and immediately re-open it, to clear the buffer?